# microtime para segundos

Tags: php

Estou verificando quanto tempo uma `API` demora para responder e estou pegando os valores no inicio com `microtime(true)` e ao final com `microtime(true)` sendo assim;

```
$start = microtime(true);
...
...
...
...
$end = microtime(true);
```

Para converter para segundos o código atual divide a subtração dos valores por 60:

`($end - $start) / 60`

Porém pesquisei muito e tudo que encontro diz respeito a dividir o valor por `1000000`, como faço para pegar a diferença destes valores em `segundos`?

Comment: Mas com o `($end - $start)` você já obtem os segundos certo?

Comment: Já tentou desta forma `date("s", $end - $start);` ?

Comment: @I_like_trains não sei rs, por isso a pergunta.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6468171/6510304